# Refactoring "x if x is not None else y" to "x or y"

Tags: python, refactoring, default-value

I came across to a piece of Python Code which technically looks like this:

```
def bar(b):
    return b*2

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.b = 10

    def foo(self, b=None):
        return bar(b if b is not None else self.b)
```

So the class has `b` as a fixed attribute, which is used as default input for a classmethod `foo`, if it is called without argument.

Please assume that `b` in this case is expected to be a float.

Please ignore unused `self.a`, it is used otherwise - i just wanted to make sure that you see that there are attributes settable by the constructor.

The usage would look like this:

```
c = MyClass(2)
c.foo(3)  # returns 3*2 = 6
c.foo()  # returns 10*2 = 20
```

In this case, I was wondering about the `foo`-method. Is this a good way to implement `self.b` as default value for `b`?

Is one of the following two suggestions by me more or less desireable? If so: why?

```
def foo(self, b=None):
    return bar(b or self.b)
```

or

```
def foo(self, b=self.b):
    return bar(b)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stick with the first option:

```
def foo(self, b=None):
    return bar(b if b is not None else self.b)
```

If you use the second option:

```
def foo(self, b=None):
    return bar(b or self.b)
```

then you will alter the behaviour of `x.foo(0)`, because zero is also falsey.

The third option is not an option:

```
def foo(self, b=self.b):
    return bar(b)
```

`self` does not exist when the method `foo()` is defined, so you cannot use `self.b` as a default argument. The definition will simply fail; or worse, it will try and use whatever is the current value of `self` when the definition is executed.

Comment: Agreed, although I'd probably eliminate that `not`: `self.b if b is None else b`

Comment: @PM2Ring I would say, that depends on what is expected to usually happen. When reading `self.b if b is None else b`, I assume that passing parameter `b` overrides the default behavior with `self.b`. When reading `b if b is not None else self.b`, I assume parameter `b` is used, but there is a default value `self.b` if the parameter has been missing. The result is the same, but the semantic is not.

Comment: Fair point, @DainDwarf. I like to minimize negation when I can, as it _tends_ to make code more readable (as well as _slightly_ more efficient). But I guess semantics trumps such considerations.

Comment: Right. I did not test my suggestions yet, so I did not notice that the second one does not compile. Also 0 evaluating to False is also a good point (though in this example, ``b`` would always be positive).